# What does the accuracy mean in the Keras progress bar?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

In Keras you'll have something like this:

```
Epoch 1/1
60000/60000 [==============================] - 297s 5ms/step - loss: 0.7048 - acc: 0.7669

60000/60000 [==============================] - 179s 3ms/step
Training Set: 
acc: 94.60%

10000/10000 [==============================] - 30s 3ms/step
Test Set: 
acc: 95.10%
```

But I fit it like so:

> model.fit(X_train, oh_y_train,
>             batch_size=512,
>             epochs=1,
>             verbose=1)

There's no validation data in the `.fit()` method, what is it measuring the accuracy from in epoch 1?

The final accuracy is way different.

Answer (score 3):

That is just accuracy on the training set, validation accuracy would be `val_acc`

Answer (score 1):

This model is fit on the training set, then validates predictions against the observed values in the training set.

So what you are looking at  `how good does this regression equation predict the same data it was fit on`.

When you get accuracy scores against a holdout sample (AKA test set) you are looking at `how good does this regression equation predict on cases that were not in the training set`

When you overfit, your accuracy scores will be much higher in the former case.